# Django не скачивается, выводит ошибку

Tags: django

Не скачивается Django, ошибка SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target [image: Это то, что выдает консоль]. Я стало быть подумал, что это из-за того, что я это делаю через эмулятор, но нет, в родной cmd всё так же. Что делать?

Comment: а какой командой вы ее скачиваете?

Comment: Выложите команду ,которой вы ставите.Выложите команду и логи _текстом_.

Comment: И вообще всё должно установиться  через `pip3 install django`.Ну или там для питона 2:`pip install django`

Comment: Да, вы помогли, всё скачалось. Команду я использовал с оф. сайта, 'pip install Dango'. Так же после скачивания питон мне порекомендовал обновить 'pip'. Я всё скачал и вс1 работает. Как мне обозначить ваш ответ правильным?

Comment: Слово Джанго пишется череза ' j' — `Django`.